# Python object method in a new thread

Tags: python

I have an object instantiated in the main thread and i wish to run one of it's methods in a different thread asynchronously . Here is the code i used:

```
obj = self._collection[index]
t1 = threading.Thread( target = obj.foo() )
t1.start()
```

The method does execute but it is in sync with the main thread.

Comment: `target = obj.foo()` runs `obj.foo` and uses the return value as `target`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `t1 = threading.Thread( target = obj.foo )` instead.

In this case, the `Thread` constructor is expecting a reference to a function...when you pass it `obj.foo()`, you are passing it the *result* of the `foo()` function. That's not what you want! Pass a reference to the function.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe i missed that :)